# If cell is N/A, how to replace it with average value of the cell above and below?

Tags: vba, excel

If the cell is N/A in excel, how can I replace this cell with the average value of the cells above and below in VBA? I would like to do this across the entire spreadsheet.

There are two situations:

1. B6:H6 - I would like to average these cells using B5:H5 and B7:H7
   (e.g. B6 is the average of B5 and B7, C6 is the average of C5 and C7 etc)
2. B10:H10 and B11:H11 - I would like to average these cells using B9:H9 and B12:H12
   (e.g. same logic here, B10 is the average of B9 and B12)
   (I would ***not*** like to use B11:H11 to calculate my average values for B10:H10)

*Please bear in mind that in the actual data, there are multiple lines of N/A (e.g. B10:H40 could all be N/A)

Many thanks for any light you may shed!

[Sample Data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5mtaf0mj4xkfmrf/Historical%20Data_31%20May%2018.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: I gather the existing cells in B6:H6, etc are formulas?

Comment: why not using formulae?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
with worksheets("sheet1")
    on error resume next
    set rng = .range("B6:H6").specialcells(xlcelltypeformulas, xlerrors)
    if not rng is nothing then
        rng.formular1c1 = "=average(r5c, r7c)"
    end if
    set rng = .range("B10:H11").specialcells(xlcelltypeformulas, xlerrors)
    if not rng is nothing then
        rng.formular1c1 = "=average(r9c, r12c)"
    end if        
end with
```

If those ranges actually contain constants and not formulas then change xlcelltypeformulas for xlcelltypeconstants.